# Compare IP to list of host/network address

Tags: c++

I appoligize but am new to C++.  At our organization we recieve a daily black list (much bigger as this is just a snippet) in the following format:

172.44.12.0

198.168.1.5

10.10.0.0

192.168.78.6

192.168.22.22

111.111.0.0

222.222.0.0

12.12.12.12

When I run the program after the code compiles I receive:

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

I am using C++ in a Linux/Unix environment.

So far, I am just spitting it out to make sure I have it formatted correctly.  Please be kind I am sure this is considered sloppy programming, I am a noob.

The name of the file is blacklist.txt which contains the IP's listed above for now.  I am only using cout to make sure my variable are defined correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

bool is_match(std::string &hay_stack, std::string &srcip) {
in_addr_t _ip = inet_addr(hay_stack.c_str());
in_addr_t _IP = inet_addr(srcip.c_str());
_ip = ntohl(_ip);
_IP = ntohl(_IP);
uint32_t mask=(_ip & 0x00ffffff == 0) ? 0xff000000 :
(_ip & 0x0000ffff == 0 ? 0xffff0000 : 0);
return ( (_ip & mask) == (_IP & mask) );
}

int main()
{
vector<std::string> lines;
lines.reserve(5000); //Assuming that the file to read can have max 5K lines

string fileName("blacklist.txt");

ifstream file;
file.open(fileName.c_str());

if(!file.is_open())
{
cerr<<"Error opening file : "<<fileName.c_str()<<endl;
return -1;
}

//Read the lines and store it in the vector
string line;
while(getline(file,line))
{
lines.push_back(line);
}

file.close();


//Dump all the lines in output
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
string h = lines[i];
string mi = "10.10.10.10";
cout<<is_match(h,mi)<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

I am expecting the output to be 10.10.10.10 10.10.0.0 (and some sort of subnet mask here)

Any help is great.

Comment: Are you able to represent IP as `unsigned int` (with length of 32b)? Than it would be: `if( (ip&mask) == subnet)` :)

Comment: I appoligize maybe it's probably my lack of C ++ knowledge but there is no mask given.  Does (ip&mask) assume you have the mask?

Comment: @SP3CH8TR yes it does. note that you can easily transform a /16 or /8 or /whatever to a mask, as it just says how many leading bits are set. e.g. /16 is the mask 0xFFFF0000 . If you don't know if it's a /16 or a /8 or a /31 etc. you got a problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

bool is_match(std::string &hay_ip, std::string &needle_ip) {
  in_addr_t _ip = inet_addr(hay_ip.c_str());
  in_addr_t _IP = inet_addr(needle_ip.c_str());
  _ip = ntohl(_ip);
  _IP = ntohl(_IP);
  uint32_t mask=(_ip & 0x0000ffff == 0) ? 0xffff0000 : 
                (_ip & 0x000000ff == 0 ? 0xffffff00 : 0xffffffff); 
  return ( (_ip & mask) == (_IP & mask) );
}
```

Comment: So I would read the file into memory first, then do a for each sort of statement putting each ip into a vector and some sort of compare with the IP I already have in a variable (I believe the IP is a string variable now) to see if there is a match?

Comment: @SP3CH8TR, updated the answer. You don't need to read all addresses before processing.

Comment: I am editing the post to include sample code.  I kind of understand what is going on in your example now I want to see where I fit it in.

Comment: I have finished editing the post.  Please be kind, I decided to learn C++ two weeks ago.  So far I am only learning by example code.

Comment: So ip_file = blacklist.txt?  Where do I feed my variable src_ip into your comparison example?

Comment: @SP3CH8TR, you can use this function to check, haven't compiled though.

Comment: I am assuming &hay_ip will be my src_ip variable and &needle_ip will be the unformatted ipaddress/subnet from the file?  In the uint32_t mask = section does one of those two lines need to be changed from _ip to _IP?  I am following it to there but I am not certian where we are formatting something that may be a subnet.

Comment: hay_ip is from file. The mask only looks at hay_ip, checks how many bits from the right are all zero in hay_ip, and creates an inverse mask.

Comment: You have been a great help, I cant't thank you enough.  I am going to edit my code and see how I do.  I want to know if someone from the blacklist successfully touched my resources.  I don't care if they get denied, I want the successes from the ASA log.  I am too poor to pay for this functionallity if it exists so I figuered the only way to do it was learn C++ and try and do it myself.  Thanks again.  I may ask another question if I am unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3):

IPv4][1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer#Common_integral_data_types) consists of 4 bytes and therefore it can (and usually is) represented as [`unsigned int`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer#Common_integral_data_types) or rather `Uint32` (32 bits long number/ 4 bytes), for example:

```
decimal:     172.16.254.1
hexadecimal: ac 10 fe 01
binary:      10101100 0001000 11111110 00000001
```

Subnet mask in `/XX` form specifies how many bits (binary ones) from the start should there be in the mask, for example:

```
/24: 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000  > 0xffffff00
/16: 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000  > 0xffff0000
```

Now you'll use [binary AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) (represented with `&` in C/C++) on `IP & Mask` which will give you this output:

```
IP:      172.16.254.1  | 0xac10fe01 | 10101100 0001000 11111110 00000001 &
Mask:    255.255.255.0 | 0xffffff00 | 11111111 1111111 11111111 00000000 =
Result:  172.16.254.0  | 0xac10fe00 | 10101100 0001000 11111110 00000000
```

Which you can now compare with subnet represented as `Uint32`, at first you'll generate mask:

```c
uint32 get_mask( const int mask_length = 24){ // for /24 mask notation
    if( mask_length > 31){
        return 0xffffffff;
    }
    return (1 << (mask_length + 1)) - 1;
    // << 25 will shift 1 to 25th place, -1 will than generate 24 ones in row
    // this wouldn't work with 32 because you would shift 1 outside 32b int
}
```

And then just simply use `&` and `==`:

```c
if( (ip&get_mask(24)) == subnet){
// if( (ip&0xffffff00) == subnet){
// if( (ip&get_mask(subnet.mask.length)) == subnet){
    // match
}
```

<sub>Note that x86 architecture uses [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) so when inspecting memory/bytes directly, you will see bytes in "*opposite order*".</sub>